# Is there Excel function that counts the text without setting a specific text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am sorry if my title is a bit confusing.

Consider the dataset that has a column with variety of text:

```
AAA
AAB
ABB
ABC
ACC
ABB
BAA
ACC
AAA
AAB
...
```

Since the column has so many different types of variable, I can't pick every text and write countif(range, "AAA") and another countif function for all text in the column. Instead, is there any Excel function that automatically 'pick' the word and then counts?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Yes there is. What result do you expect from your given dataset. You may need `UNIQUE()` function.

Comment: Just reference a blank cell in the criteria argument and then you can type in a text value in the blank cell. You could also copy all text values to another column, click on remove duplicates, and write the function next to the 1st text value and reference it as criteria. Then drag the formula down to fill the cells next to the remaining text values.

Comment: You can get a list of unique values from that list using UNIQUE()

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to count how many times does each *text* appears in the column. You can do this real easy in 2 ways:

[image]

**With Formula**
My formula in B1 is `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10;A1)`. Just drag down

**With Pivot Tables**: You can create a Pivot Table to list each **unique** value and then count how many times does each **unique text** appears. Create the Pivot Table, and take your single column into Rows Section and into Values Section. It takes like 5 clics only...